# Posting form data to a controller method using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**THE PROBLEM**

I want to post form data to a controller asynchronously using AJAX. Here's a simplified view of my JavaScript:

```
function SendForm() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('value1', 'hello');
  formData.append('value2', 'world');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.upload.onload = function() {
    // stuff that happens on the callback
  };
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://server/controller/SomeAction', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

The problem begins on the server side where all the method parameters are null.

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult SomeAction(string value1, string value2)
{
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2)) { throw new Exception("World not found."); }
  return Content("something");
}
```

**THE QUESTION**

My question is, why are all the method parameters null?

**EXTRA RESEARCH**

I've looked inside the request stream, and I can see from the length that there is content there, but for whatever reason MVC has failed to match the parameters I specified in the FormData object to the parameters in the methed in the controller.

**WHY AM I DOING THIS?**

Yes, I want to POST the data. I've simplified the example, but I want to post more data than can be placed on a URL, so a REST method (passing the data on the querystring) is not acceptable for this solution.

Comment: are you uploading a file ?

Comment: Yes, I will want to upload a file. I use formData.append('file', fileObject, fileObject.name), where the fileObject is obtain from the fileInputElement.files[0]. On the server side, I've been trying to use HttpPostedFileBase to get the file. I also send some supplementary params which are specific to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function SendForm() {
   var formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('value1', 'hello');
   formData.append('value2', 'world');
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://server/controller/SomeAction",
     type: 'post',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
        // ..... any success code you want
    }
   });
```

Comment: I installed jQuery and tried your suggestion. Firefox returns the following error: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData. To fix it, I added "processData: false". It still didn't work, so based on another SO I found, I added "contentType: false" and "cache: false". This now seems to be working, so I'll do a little more testing.

Comment: you can pass the strings seperately in data

Comment: Thanks Darrell. If you make the three corrections I discovered were required, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I've changed :-).You can also pass data as Json then process data need not be false ..i think(You were passing a Javascript object.)ContentType can be Json in that case.Anyways since this code works  i think we can stay with the edited code :-)

Comment: Hi Mark :-) . Does it look ok :-)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up using. :)

Answer (score 2):

try to make the ajax call this way, i think it is the best way to make request

```
    function SendForm() {
            var data = {};
            data.value1 = "Hello";
            data.value2 = "World";

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://server/controller/SomeAction",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
                success: function (data) {
                    // your code in success
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
        }
```

---

and the action method will be

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SomeAction(string value1, string value2)
 {
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2)) 
    { 
     throw new Exception("World not found."); 
    }
     return Json("something");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function SendForm() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('value1', 'hello');
  formData.append('value2', 'world');
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://server/controller/SomeAction",
    type: 'post',
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
    data: { formData: formData, value1: "hello", value2: "world"},
    success: function (data) {
    // ..... any success code you want
    }
  });
```

> And Recieve JSON at server side

Please try this .I am Unable to run the code on a project now.This is the theory though ,You can pass the data seperately using AJAX

> If Only value1 and value2 is reqd   - Server

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SomeAction(string value1, string value2)
 {
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2)) { throw 
     new Exception("World not found."); }
     return Content("something");
   }
```

> JQuery

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://server/controller/SomeAction",
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: { value1: "hello", value2: "world"},
    success: function (data) {
    // ..... any success code you want
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using AJAX this way,

```
function SendForm() {      
       $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/controller/SomeAction',
                data: { value1 : 'hello', value2 : 'world' },
                success: function (result) {
                    //Your success code here..
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {                        
                    if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
                        alert("Value Not found");
                    }
                }
            });
     }
```

You can find the `value1` and `value2` to server side.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult SomeAction(string value1, string value2)
{
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value1) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value2)) { throw new Exception("World not found."); }
  return Content("something");
}
```